# Using Gson and JsonObject to format and parse data

Tags: json, parsing, gson

I am using [JsonObject](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) and [Gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) to format the data i need to send in the form of String and then retrieve and parse it somewhere else. 
This is my simple code which is not working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Gson g = new Gson();
    Gson listG = new Gson();
    ArrayList<String> l= new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("abcd");
    l.add("efgh");
    l.add("ijkl");

    String list = listG.toJson(l);

    JsonObject jObject = new JsonObject();
    jObject.addProperty("command" , 1);
    jObject.addProperty("message" , "this is a test message");
    jObject.addProperty("list" , list);

    String toSend = g.toJson(jObject);
    System.out.println(toSend);  

    Gson rec = new Gson();
    JsonObject newObj = rec.fromJson(toSend, JsonObject.class);
    System.out.println(newObj);  // getting nothing in newObj


}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use:

```
JsonObject newObj = new JsonParser().parse(toSend).getAsJsonObject();
```

Lots of calls in there, but the gist is to use the [JsonParser](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) class.